# How can I disable some code without commenting it out or removing it?

Tags: comment

When I need to disable code without removing it, I comment it out. I find this clumsy, especially when the code is a function definition or some other kind of cohesive whole, such as:

```
(global-set-key "\C-x" 'do-stuff)
(defun do-stuff () ...)
```

Is there a better way? I think something like the following would be nice:

```
(off
   (global-set-key "\C-x" 'do-stuff)
   (defun do-stuff () ...))
```

I understand I can define `off` myself, but isn’t there a standard way to do this?

Comment: What's the problem with commenting things out?  Selecting the code and typing `M-;` is easy, no?  Wrapping your `off` form around something still requires acting on the beginning and the end of the forms you're disabling, so I don't see an advantage of that over the commenting workflow which acts on those exact same positions.

Comment: @phils: The way Elisp handles `;` is based on lines of text instead of S-structures. If we want to comment some code, we first need to make them separate from the code snippet. Sometimes it is annoying. It would be nice to use an S-expression-based approach to comment some code. I also asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75775454/20212483) which is related to this topic.

Comment: @phils `off` conveys my intention to turn code off. Comments can be used for a lot of other purposes. Also, sometimes, albeit infrequently, I like disabled code to keep being editable without loosing indentation and highlighting. For instance, it’s harder to read commented-out, not highlighted, code.

Comment: @Shynur Emacs breaks the lines for you, if necessary, when you comment out a region, and there's a standard key binding for joining lines if uncommenting again.  I can only speak for myself of course, but I don't personally find it annoying.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question generally is to use *block*-commenting. That's essentially what you're asking for by asking for a `(off`...`)` envelope. Think of your `(off` as starting a comment block and the corresponding `)` as ending it.

Unlike Common Lisp, Emacs Lisp doesn't provide a block-commenting feature. That is, it provides only a `comment-start` string, which is `";"`, and no `comment-end` string -- that's the empty string, `""`.

But you can use the ordinary end-of-line commenting (`;`) to achieve the effect of block-commenting, provided you have a command that not only lets you (1) comment out code that might, itself, contain comments -- in other words, nest commented code, but also (2) ***un***nest a given level of such a (pseudo) block comment.

The standard command `comment-region` comes close to this description. And the standard command `comment-dwim` also comes (less) close to it.

`comment-region` lets you nest and unnest a given number of `;` commenting. `comment-dwim` doesn't do (un)nesting well. It tries to both comment out a region and add an end-of-line comment (or reposition such an existing comment).

I use my command `comment-region-lines`, from library [`misc-cmds.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/misc-cmds.el). It does what `comment-region` does, except that it comments or uncomments whole lines. I bind it to `C-x C-;` (which by default is bound `comment-line`). And I use `M-;` (bound to `comment-dwim`) only for end-of-line commenting.

Here's the doc of standard command `comment-region`.

> Comment or uncomment each line in the region.
>
> With just `C-u` prefix arg, uncomment each line in region `BEG` .. `END`.
>
> Numeric prefix `ARG` means use `ARG` comment characters.
> If `ARG` is negative, delete that many comment characters instead.
>
> The strings used as comment starts are built from `comment-start`
> and `comment-padding`; the strings used as comment ends are built
> from `comment-end` and `comment-padding`.
>
> By default, the `comment-start` markers are inserted at the
> current indentation of the region, and comments are terminated on
> each line (even for syntaxes in which newline does not end the
> comment and blank lines do not get comments).  This can be
> changed with `comment-style`.

---

In your question you also speak about the distraction that commenting code can introduce. For that, I suggest command `https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideOrIgnoreComments` from my library [`hide-comnt.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideOrIgnoreComments).

It hides the comments in the active region (or the whole buffer, if no active region). With a prefix arg it shows the hidden comments.
Or use command `hide/show-comments-toggle`, which toggles hiding/showing commented text.

There's also Lisp macro `with-comments-hidden`, for hiding/ignoring comments while executing some code, i.e., when you want some code to ignore the commented text.

And there are some user options that control comment hiding:

> - `hide-whitespace-before-comment-flag` – If non-`nil` then whitespace preceding a comment is hidden. Empty lines (newline chars) are not hidden, however.
> - `ignore-comments-flag` – If `nil` then `with-comments-hidden` does not ignore comments.
> - `show-invisible-comments-shows-all` – If non-`nil` then showing comments after hiding them shows all text that was invisible, however it was made so. The default is `nil`: make visible only text that was made invisible by `hide/show-comments`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. I do use `comment-region`. About hiding comments, I wouldn’t want to do that indiscriminately. Information provided by comments is rarely less valuable than information provided by code to me – with the obvious exception of commented-out code.

Answer (score 1):

This is already a functionality in emacs:

```
(ignore
 ...)
```

See: C-h f ignore.

As noted by @shynur, that is a function though, so the arguments will be evaluated, which is not desirable. A macro is the path to avoid that, but it will at a minimum expand to nil. There are scenarios where that is not the right thing to do though (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75775454/how-to-define-a-macro-that-returns-nothing), and there are likewise scenarios where it is not correct to return nothing (i.e. as if the code was not there).

For the first case consider:

```
(+ 8 (off 4))
```

if off returns nil, this will be an error since you can't add 8 and nil.

For the second case example, consider:

```
(message "%s" (off (some-code)))
```

That will give rise to an error if somehow the off macro somehow results in nothing in that position because there would not be enough arguments for the format string.

There isn't a solution for both issues I think.

A comment approach is to wrap the body in (progn ...), and use something like `lispy-comment` that comments out the sexp if you type ; in front of it, and C-u ; to uncomment the body. There is nothing more simple than this. Even if you had a macro for `off`, undoing it is more work than this solution, unless you do something like replace off with progn I think.

Comment: No, it is a function, whose arguments will be evaluated.

Comment: True, thanks  for noting it. I expanded my answer a little.